# Write Action Listener to close program java

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have written code to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. My action listener is not closing the program when clicking on the X in the top right of the window. Any guidance is appreciated. It seems the main class is not recognizing the code for the defaultcloseopertion.

```
 import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TemperatureConversion extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    private final Label lblInput;
    private final Label lblOutput;
    private final TextField tfInput;
    private final TextField tfOutput;
    private double farenheit;
    private double celcius;

    public TemperatureConversion()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());



        lblInput = new Label ("Enter degrees in Farenheit: ");
        add(lblInput);

        tfInput = new TextField(10);
        add(tfInput);
        tfInput.addActionListener(this);


        lblOutput = new Label("Degrees in celcius:");
        add(lblOutput);

        tfOutput = new TextField(10);
        tfOutput.setEditable(false);
        add(tfOutput);

        setTitle("Farenheit to Celcius Conversion");
        setSize(350, 120);
        setVisible(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        farenheit = Integer.parseInt(tfInput.getText());
        celcius = (5.0/9)*(farenheit -32);
        tfInput.setText("");
        tfOutput.setText(celcius + "");


    }
}
```

2nd file includes main class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TemperatureConversionTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TemperatureConversion textFieldFrame = new TemperatureConversion();
        textFieldFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        textFieldFrame.setSize(350, 100);
        textFieldFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-) is a member method of `JFrame` not `java.awt.Frame`

```
public class TemperatureConversion extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the below method after the `setVisible(true);` method.

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

this needs to be done explicitly in `swing`. One more thing that you need to address would be change the class signature to extend `JFrame` instead of `Frame`. Since, `Frame` is an `awt` library where as `JFrame` comes from swing.

```
public class TemperatureConversion extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```